# Width issue - Outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, outlook-2010

This is my stripped code:

```
<table border="0" width="650" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="border-style: none; background-color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="210" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Times New Roman, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif; text-align: center; word-break: break-all;">
<span id="" class="txt" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 22px;">
    Some Text
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-style: none; background-color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Times New Roman, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif; text-align: left;">
<span id="sma" class="txt" style="font-size: 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #000;">
    <img src="picture_95x95.jpg" align="left" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Smartfon" style="border-style: none; display: block;" />
</span>
</td>
<td>
<table border="0" width="100" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="border-style: none; background-color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Times New Roman, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif; text-align: right; word-break: break-all;">
<span id="pra" class="txt" style="font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal; color: #a40133; line-height: 44px;">
    Text X1
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Times New Roman, Tahoma, Trebuchet, sans-serif; text-align: center; background-color: #a40133; border-radius: 5px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; word-break: break-all;">
<span id="cha" class="txt" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
<a href="#" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none;">
    Text X2
</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is the issue. Table width is strictly 210, but in outlook it looks like 211. i don't know how to get rid of this 1px. i tried almost everything and now i'm speechless.

any idea would be appreciated. thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it's adding the border to the width of the table? Making it 212?

Answer (score 0):

In your code change the following from

```
 <table border="0" width="210" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #fff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
```

to

```
<table border="0" width="212" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 5px; background-color: #fff; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
```

check the below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3H2g6/5/

Comment: I tried this. Now the size of table is strictly 209 :-( Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: I have updated my answer. check it now, and check the jsfiddle if any clarification needed.

Comment: Thank you.  I removed "border-collapse: collapse". now i have table width 214. still, i got 2 extra pixels. even if i set table width to 208, it won't work because other email client will set this value to 208 instead of 210.

Comment: :) remove table width property and add width:210px for the table column.

Comment: could you show me the proper code? cause i'm not sure. thank you.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle above. check it out.

Comment: thanks, but result is the same. always table width is set to 212 (only outlook). i guess it's time to give up :-)